# Nagios send sms with Cisco CallManager

Tags: nagios, cisco

I have a Cisco CallManager version 5.12 and i wanted to send sms with the CallManager when nagios host is down. I have googleit and cant find nothing.

Cumprimentos,
Sérgio Marques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cisco CallManager does not send sms. You need an sms gateway or find a provider that offers an sms service you can use to send sms through http(s) or api

Comment: Thanks for the answer